# How to do load and performance testing of Hadoop cluster?

Tags: performance, hadoop, load, performance-testing, mapr

Are there any tools to generate an automated scenario with a predefined ramp up of user requests (running same map-reduce job) and monitoring some specific metrics of Hadoop cluster under load? I am looking ideally for something like [LoadRunner](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/V2/GetPDF.aspx/4AA5-0954ENW.pdf) but free/open source tool.

The tool does not have to have a cool UI but rather an ability to record and save scenarios that include a ramp up and a rendezvous point for several users (wait until other users reach some point and do some action simultaneously).

The Hadoop distribution I am going to test is the latest MapR.

Searching internet did not bring any good free alternatives to HP LoadRunner. In case you had an experience with Hadoop (or MapR in particular) load testing, please share what tool you have used.

Comment: Did you check GridMix? https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/gridmix.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Does not have everything I need but might be usefull if no better alternative exists.

Comment: You could also check with MapR documentation. I am sure they'll have some perf. testing tools. You can also use "tera*" (teragen, terasort, teravalidate) and TPC-DS, TPC-H for benchmarking (http://www.tpc.org/tpcds/).

Answer (score 0):

Every solution you will look at has both a tool quotient and a labor quotient in the total price.  There are many open source tools which take the tool cost to zero but the labor charge is so high that your total cost to deliver will be higher than a purchase of a commercial tool with a lower labor charge.  Also, many people look at performance testing tools as load generation alone, ignoring the automated collection of monitoring data and the analysis of the results where you can pin an increase in response times with a correlated use of resources at the same time.   This is a laborious process made longer to do when you are using decoupled tools.

As you have mentioned LoadRunner, when you are provided a tool you should compare what is available in that tool to whatever you are provided.   For instance, 
there are Java, C, C++ & VB interfaces available in LoadRunner.  You are going to find a way to exercise your map and reduce infrastructure. Compare the integrated monitoring capabilities (native/SNMP/terminal user with command line...) as well as analysis and reporting.   Where capabilities do not exist you will either need to build the capability or acquire it elsewhere.

You have also brought up the concept of Rendezvous.  You will want to be careful with its application in any tool.  Unless you have a very large population the odds of Simultaneous collision in the same area of code/action at the same time becomes quite small.  Humans are chaotic instruments, arriving and departing independently from one another.   On the other hand, if you are automating an agent which is based upon a clock tick then rendezvous makes a lot more sense.   Taking a look at your job submission logs by IP address can provide an objective model for how many are submitted simultaneously (rendezvous) versus how many are running concurrently. I audit a lot of tests and rendezvous is the most abused item across tools, resulting in thousands of lost engineering hours chasing engineering ghosts that would never occur in natural use.